# How to pass output of one command as env variables to another

Tags: bash, npm

I have a bash script that when ran, produces output like this:

```
VAR1=test
VAR2=test
```

I want to pass these variables as environment variables to an npm script, which in this case is just running `mocha` in the current directory, like if I was running `VAR1=test VAR2=test mocha`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great design for a bash script to output shell variable assignments like that, but you can work around it with a wrapper script `runwithvars`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -a                 # Auto-export all new variables
eval "$(mybashscript)" # Perform whichever actions the script outputs
exec "$@"              # Execute the specified command
```

Now you can use `runwithvars mocha` to run `mocha` with those variables.

Note that if the script outputs key-value pairs instead of shell variable assignments, e.g. `VAR1=some value with spaces` instead of `VAR1='some value with spaces'`, then this answer does not apply and could be fragile or dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Use `export`:

```
export VAR1=test
export VAR2=test
```